# Is there any way to read form value of checked box in the backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

```
<form>
<table class="tableheight" id="customers">
           <tbody style='height:270px;display:block;overflow:auto;width:286px'>
           <tr>
            <th style="  border-top-left-radius: 10px;">Add a Friend</th>
            <th style="  border-top-right-radius: 10px;text-align:center;"><i style="color:green;font-size:25px;background-color:white;" class="fas fa-check-circle"></i></th>
            </tr>
            <% if(friend.length==0){ %>
           <h2> No Bookmarks Added Yet! </h2>
             <% } %>
             <% friend.forEach(function(f,i){ %>
             <tr>
              <td style="padding-right:110px;"><%= f.name %></td>
              <td style="text-align:center;"><input type="checkbox" name="<%= f.name %>">
              </td>
               </tr>
               <% }) %>
            </tbody>
              </table>
     </div>
    </form>
```

Unable to read data of form in the backend. Is there a way to read it?
I have tried req.body.cur where cur is the value of <%= f.name %>
The issue is only with friend.forEach loop